# Why command `file --mime-type` and `mimetype` give different results for the same file?

Tags: file, ubuntu, mime-types, bsc, octet-stream

I have a file that contains a single text character (C). There is no line-feed character or similar in the file.

I am in Ubuntu 20.04.1.

When I use the command `file --mime-type` with this file the command says that the file is an `application/octet-stream` file, but if I use the command `mimetype` with this file the command says that the file is a `text/plain` file.

Why do these two tools that I considered more or less equivalent differ in guessing the mimetype of this particular file?

I also found that using the `file` command without arguments with the same file produces the output `very short file (no magic)`. Is that the reason that the command is failing its guess?

What is the meaning of this? How this implementation is different from the implementation of the mime-type command?

In this case I would say that the command `file --mime-type` has a bug since I clearly see that the file is actually a text file. Why this happens?

Here is a screenshot of the relevant commands and its results:

[image: commands and its output]